# Changing backgroud color of a row in grid view with a link button

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I have grid view and there is a link button inside it. the only thing that i want to do is to changing selected row background color. I mean as i click on the link button(Edit), the color of that row must be changed.I use this code but it doesn't work for me.I also have ID of my record from my command grid view.
Can anybody help me?

code:

```
int idx = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);

            idx = idx - (GridView3.PageSize * GridView3.PageIndex);

            int ID = (int)GridView3.DataKeys[idx].Value;

         //   GridView3.SelectedRowStyle[idx].backgroundColor= "White";
            Session["ID"] = ID;
            GridView3.EditRowStyle.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.LightYellow;
```

[image]

Comment: is the Edit link button has a command Name property Value ?

Comment: I think no. It has only LinkButton1_Command in it's events to write our commands there.

Answer (score 0):

If your Link Button has `CommandName` with "`Edit`" value then you can use GridView styles properties

```
..........
  </Columns>

       <selectedrowstyle backcolor="LightYellow"
         forecolor="DarkBlue"
         font-bold="true"/>  

     </asp:gridview>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answering. Is there any asp command to do that?
Because i have the idx of that row.